# iPhone SDK - Problem Parsing XML from RSS feed

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, rss

I made an RSS reader that gets a feed from blogspot.
The text from the story, title, etc. works fine.
But the images posted inthe feed show up as links instead of an image.
How can I display the images?

Comment: can you post the sample xml or give link to xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I use to dynamically download images into a list:

```
//starts the downloading of the image
- (void) downloadImage
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(imageDownloadWorker:) 
                             toTarget:self 
                           withObject:[self getAvatarUrl]/*here goes your url*/];
}

//does something with the image once loaded
- (void)imageLoaded:(UIImage *)image
{   
    //do something
}

//downloads the image
- (void)imageDownloadWorker:(NSString *)urlString
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool  = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSURL             *url   = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData            *data  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage           *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(imageLoaded:) 
                           withObject:[image autorelease]
                        waitUntilDone:YES];
    [pool drain];
}
```

Hope it helps, good luck!